# Docker Mailcow: How to renew the certificate when change domains on a setup with nginx as reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, ssl, email-server, docker, docker-compose

I have setup to a [mailcow-dockerized](https://mailcow.email/) solution to my server and I wanted to change my mailserver's the domain from mail.example.ml to mail.example.*tk* but When I did it my browser was complaining about the wrong certificate when I visited it the http://mail.example.tk on it.

Also the administration app was running behind nginx running as reverse proxy with the following renewed vhost configuration:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name mail.thundermail.tk;

   location /.well-known {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/.well-known ;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;

   }

   location / {
        rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
   }

}

server {
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name mail.thundermail.tk;

 ssl_certificate     /opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl/cert.pem;
 ssl_certificate_key /opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl/key.pem;
 ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;


 location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 100m;
 }
}
```

Please keep in ming that the mailcow:dockerized solution is generating the certificates in `opt/docker-mailcow/data/assets/ssl` path.

Do you fellows have an idea how to generate the new Certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1 `cd ^path_where_mailcow_dockerized_is_installed^`
2 On `mailcow.conf` change the line starting with `MAILCOW_HOSTNAME` into

```
MAILCOW_HOSTNAME=mail.example.tk
```

3 Run: `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`

4 Restart nginx. (In debian or debian based linux distros this can be done via `sudo service nginx restart` command)

Comment: If this indeed does answer your question, please mark it as answered. Otherwise the question forever cycles to the top of Active questions.